# C# Generics specify type dynamically via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to set type T of a generic list via reflection. Here is my code:

```
if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    Type itemType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var result = MyGenericMethod<itemType>(url);   
}
```

This is giving me a syntax error. How can set the type argument T of generic type via reflection ?

Thanks

Comment: ... or of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059945/generate-generic-type-at-runtime) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151464/how-to-dynamically-create-generic-c-sharp-object-using-reflection) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965893/c-sharp-creating-an-unknown-generic-type-at-runtime) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/dynamically-create-a-generic-type-for-template) ... this has been asked **and answered** many times before, please *do* look for duplicates *before* asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this by utilizing `Invoke` and `MakeGenericMethod`.

You will need to know the name of the class it is executing in, lets call it `ClassName`. The binding flags are also very important, if they are incorrect (guessing here since you don't show a method signature) then the MethodInfo will be null and you will get an exception.

```
if(/*noted conditions in question*/)
{
   Type itemType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
   Type ThisClass = typeof(ClassName);
   MethodInfo mi = ThisClass.GetMethod("MyGenericMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   MethodInfo miConstructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(itemType);
   object[] args = { url };
   var result = miConstructed.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty example:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        Printer instance = new Printer( );
        Type type = typeof( string );

        typeof( Printer ).GetMethod( "print" )
            .MakeGenericMethod( type )             // <-- Here
            .Invoke( instance, new object[ ] { "Hello World!" } );
    }
}

class Printer {
    public void Print<T>( T t ) {
        Console.WriteLine( t.ToString( ) );
    }
}
```

You get the method with reflection, as usual, then add the generic parameter(s) and invoke it.